# Ruby on Rails - before_action as action preventer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

**Edit:** The original goal was to use `before_action` as blocker of `show` action for user that not Admin neither Current. In other words let only Admin or Current user execute `show` action. From my experience I understood that it's the easy way to implement it is by blocking the execution from inside of the action, but it leads to code duplication.

**Original:** I'm trying to build some complex before_action configuration:

[image]

in boolean logic I can configure it as:
Logged_in and (Admin or Current)

Logged_in/Not Logged in, Admin and Current function already defined

```
before_action :logged_in_user,      only: [:show]
before_action :current_user,        only: [:show]    #correct - the some 
before_action :admin_user,          only: [:show]
```

It should work by the logic that defined up

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly here. Can you add more context/explanations/code?

Comment: I'm trying to block the access to show action for user that not meet the conditions

Comment: something like ?: `before_action :redirect_if_not_allowed`, and then in your `redirect_if_not_allowed` function: `redirect_to index_path if not_logged_in || logged_in_but_not_admin`, and then you define the logic in your `not_logged_in` and `logged_in_but_not_admin`.

Comment: Thanks fanta! I have tried something similar but the functions (Loggen in Admin, etc) already defined and I didn't succeed to build "redirect_if_not_allowed" function

Comment: You might use a gem that already defines these methods. Check your helpers and your gems.

Comment: Yes, It's in the helpers. But there is no way to use it controller without changing it?

Comment: @LukeS if the negative ranking done by one of you. can you please remove it?

Comment: What is an example of "logged in" user that is not "current"?

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong term, but the example is: User A "logged in" want to see User B profile. User A is not "current" for User B

Answer (score 1):

You're conflating two very different things here - authentication and authorization.

You don't really need a a very complex logic gate - you need to seperate callbacks for each concern.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  private

    def authenticate_user!
      flash[:error] = "Please sign in."
      redirect_to new_session_path and return
    end
end
```

So lets setup a pretty simple example of authentication and authorization. The rules are as follows:

---

- any visitor may view the index and show
- any signed in user may create new books
- the user that has created a book or an admin may alter existing records

---

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show, :index]
  before_action :set_book, except: [:new, :index]
  before_action :authorize!, except: [:new, :create, :show, :index]

  private 

    def set_book    
      @user = Book.find(params[:id])
    end

    def authorize!
      unless @book.user == current_user || current_user.admin?
        redirect_to users_path, alert: 'You are not authorized.' and return
      end
    end
end
```

However you should start by integrating and learning existing solutions such as Devise, CanCanCan and Pundit. When you have mastered that you can roll your own.

Comment: Thank you @max ! now I'm thikning that it's better to implement it inside the action

Comment: No, its not better to implement it in the action. That leads to you duplicating the same authentication / authorization logic all over your controllers.

Comment: may I ask you to vote for the question? this question was closed because I write it not clear, but I have edited it